# Coding problem, can't make array out of API elements, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

Ok,this is the first time I post on stackoverflow,so basically I am new to JS, React, Web Dev in general and I am having trouble making an array out of some data in the JSON response of an API.

I followed many similar tutorials for this but I can't seem to get it right, maybe I am making mistakes with the path.

This is some of the JSON:

```
meta: {code: 200}
   response:
    holidays: Array(34)
           0:
            date:
             datetime: {year: 2019, month: 1, day: 1}
             iso: "2019-01-01"
__proto__: Object
description: "New Year’s Day (Anul Nou) and the following day, on January 1 and 2 respectively, are annual holidays in Romania."
locations: "All"
name: "New Year's Day"
states: "All"
type: ["National holiday"]
__proto__: Object
           1: {name: "Day after New Year's Day", description: "Both New Year’s Day (Anul Nou) and the following d…d 2 respectively, are annual holidays in Romania.", date: {…}, type: Array(1), locations: "All", …}
           2: {name: "Unification Day", description: "Unification Day celebrates the political union bet…ch is deemed as the foundation of modern Romania.", date: {…}, type: Array(1), locations: "All", …}
```

This is how i tried to access the API  with a componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {

   const endpoint = 'https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?api_key=065cc39ad5c1967ae719985ce3850f264f0215b7015d801b098df1ca9fca725b&country=RO&year=2019';
   fetch(endpoint)
   .then(results => results.json())
 }
```

And this is how I tried to make a function that takes the year month and day of all the elements in the array and returns another array with all the dates only:

```
 holidayDateArray(data){
   let holidayDates= data;
   let holidays= holidayDates.response.holidays;
   let holidaysArray= holidays.map((items, i)=>{
     return {items.date.datetime.year}+" "+{items.date.datetime.month}+" "+{items.date.datetime.day}
   });
 }
```

Basically I want the holidayDateArray function to return an array made out of the dates of all the elements in the holidays array.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, try making a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your Json isn’t formatted properly. I would fix this before attempting anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const endpoint = 'https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?api_key=065cc39ad5c1967ae719985ce3850f264f0215b7015d801b098df1ca9fca725b&country=RO&year=2019';

    fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(myJson => {
        const listOfDates = this.getListOfDates(myJson);
        //set listOfDates to a state variable / instance variable and use as necessary
        console.log(listOfDates);
      });
  }

  getListOfDates(myJson) {
    const holidayLists = myJson.response.holidays;
    const dateList = holidayLists.map(holidayListItem => {
      const dateTime = holidayListItem.date.datetime;
      // return dateTime.iso; 
      return `${dateTime.year} ${dateTime.month} ${dateTime.day}`;
    });
    return dateList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   fetch(endpoint)
   .then(results => results.json()).then(r => console.log($.map(r.response.holidays, h => h.date)))
```

results.json() will return a promise,for when the deserialization is done, so you have to await it too. After that you can iterate over all elements in the array with $.map and return back an array based on the property `date`